# Unable to get input field `value` assigned using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am using Laravel with Angular JS for forms.  I got a text box in the form as below

```
<input type="text" name="removedSiblings" ng-model="form.removedSiblings"
       id="div_removedSiblings" class="form-control">
```

Using Javascript I am assigning a value (a button click)

```
var elem = document.getElementById('div_removedSiblings');
elem.value = 'malai';
```

Got the below code inside the Controller PHP

```
$removedSiblings = \Input::get('removedSiblings');
logger($removedSiblings);
```

I always get null value for $removedSiblings variable whenever the field gets value using the javascript.

But, when I type a value manually inside the text box, then that value is printed inside the controller.

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AngularJS framework does not watch the `value` property of `<input>` elements. It only updates the model after user input or an update from inside the framework.

Use the `ng-click` directive for the button:

```
<button ng-click="form.removedSiblings = 'malai'">
    Click me
</button>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-click Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Answer (score 0):

It's is because of the usage of ng-model which uses two way binding.. Try to set the value on the controller scope variable which is form.removedSiblings.

hope this helps.